# Stripe checkout session with multi currency conversion depend on locale

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I've using the Stripe checkout session to create a checkout page for my app using.
All products price default currency is 'USD'. But I want to transfer to multi-currencies depend on the locale browser for customers in the overseas USA.

Example: Product price is **50 'USD'**

If I living in **Germany** so the checkout should be generation all banking in **Germany** with Stripe supported and the amount should be converted to **42.33 'EUR'**

```
stripeServer.checkout.sessions.create({
    customer_email: email,
    line_items: [
      {
        price: 'price_id'
      }
    ],
    payment_method_types: mode === STRIPE.PAYMENT_TYPE.SUBSCRIPTION ? ['card'] : ['card', 'alipay'],
    mode,
    billing_address_collection: 'auto',
    locale: location || 'auto',
```

But now, it just transfers the language depend on location, the price is still just 'USD' instead of 'EUR'

[Stripe checkout session images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b2jw.png)

I've read the docs of Stripe but only support the payouts to get profit billing to your account banking https://stripe.com/docs/payouts

So now if an Indian Customer or Singapore customer wants to payment, I need to create a new price ID with their country currency. Do we have another solution for this?

Thank for your advice and support for me

Comment: How did you end up solving this? Did you have to create multiple price points like the below answer? I want it to be auto-converted for every currency out there, rather than me having to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stripe doesn't support that kind of automatic currency conversion today, no.

If you want to charge customers in different locations in different currencies, then you have to tell Stripe to charge an amount X in currency Y based on your own specific business logic.

If using Checkout, the idea is you would create a Product and can define various Prices in different currencies , https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide .
The amount you use for the local currency is something you as the merchant decide when setting this up. So yes, as you describe, you want to create a new Price for their country/currency combo.

More generally I want to point out that you probably **don’t** want to just do a straight conversion, you want to actually consciously price your product according to local  competitors and purchase power like the Big Mac Index. If you Google “price localisation” there’s lots of blogs about this kind of thing. For example $50 is about 3,600INR, but the average monthly salary in India is (taking a random example from Google), 16,000INR. So that "$50" item is a much more expensive proposition to your Indian customer in that country if you just do straight conversions instead of consciously pricing your product.

Answer (score 2):

Stripe has announced they are working on automatic currency conversion API. So, it's better to register your email on the below page, so that they can inform you once the feature is added.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/present-local-currencies